# How to achieve "old web" look with CSS

Tags: css

And with old web look I mean something like this: http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html

Now, that's the oldest website. But it doesn't have a lot of content so it doesn't show off that much. I mean like, before good looking CSS. Before you had to worry that much about looks, compared to today. Before CSS if there was that. I am aware that before you styled it with HTML attributes, and not CSS.

So how do I achieve that look? I'm pretty sure different browsers have different default styles, that may vary. So I'm asking for a .css file that makes it all look like back then. Is there such a thing?

BTW, in case you haven't noticed at this point. I love the look the old web had. It's so primitive yet you could make such readable websites, I'm always impressed by it.

So how do I do this? Of course I would be using HTML5 for the structure and CSS for the styling, but I want to achieve that look.

Comment: Don't use a stylesheet.  Done!

Comment: The problem with your question is that "that look", as you perceive it, is only the look your browser, with your settings, will generate for that website.

Comment: Seriously, as @Mash says, don't style it and your browser will produce something similar. If you look at the page source, they have no stylesheet. And if you want to be really old-school, you can use a table like they did.

Comment: @Floris So if I don't use *any* stylesheet at all it'll look like I want it to? What I want is sort of a normalize.css so that all the defaults are the same, but still has that old web look.

Comment: @Eduan - no that is not what I said. When you use no stylesheet (and use use tags like `<strong>` etc) you will get the look you seem to like _when you use your browser_. Other people, with other browsers, may see something completely different (font etc). This is because "basic" HTML says "I will leave the details of the rendering up to you". It is the exact opposite of pdf, which creates "exactly the same look regardless of platform" (well that's the idea). If you want a "particular look", you need to describe _exactly_ what you want - otherwise you don't control it. Even "old" has a format.

Comment: @Floris Got ya. It'll leave the rendering up to the browser, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use pixelated images, ugly animated GIFs, hyperlinks everywhere, poor structure, no CSS, MIDI tracks, and done!

Comment: You forgot the "Under Construction" images/icons.

Comment: I knew I forgot something.

Answer (score 2):

You want **UGLY**? Ok, I know something ugly. Its called **Geo for Bootstrap**

[**Check it out**](http://divshot.github.io/geo-bootstrap/)

And I also give you [something beautiful](http://purecss.io/)

Comment: You sure found nicely contrasting style sheets! It doesn't really answer the question but it did trigger a smile.